# Rails.cache.fetch exception: TypeError (<ModelName> can't be referred to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm implementing some caching by using the nifty `Rails.cache.fetch`.  However, in one particular instance, sometimes I encounter an exception:

```
TypeError in EmloController#index

Emlo can't be referred to

app/controllers/emlo_controller.rb:320:in `get_employees'
app/controllers/emlo_controller.rb:356:in `prepare_json_response'
app/controllers/emlo_controller.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in index'
app/controllers/emlo_controller.rb:15:in `index'
```

It seems the fetch will always explode (with the above) on the first try, and then work fine as long as the fetch is within the expiration.  I know I'm missing something, so a fresh pair of eyes would be nice.

Here's the method which invokes the cache fetch:

```ruby
def get_employees

  # This is for a AJAX refresh loop, so a 5-second cache actually helps quite a bit
  Rails.cache.fetch('emlo_all', :expires_in => 5.seconds, :race_condition_ttl => 1) do

    conditions = (params[:id]) ? {:user_id => params[:id]} : nil

    selections = [
      'employee_locations.id AS emlo_id',
      'employee_locations.status_id',
      'employee_locations.notes',
      'employee_locations.until',
      'employee_locations.updated_at',
      'employee_locations.user_id',
      'location_states.id AS state_id',
      'location_states.title AS status_string',
      'location_states.font_color',
      'location_states.bg_color',
      'users.displayname',
      'users.email',
      'users.mobile',
      'users.department',
      'users.extension',
      'users.guid',
      'users.dn'
    ].join(', ')

    Emlo.all(
        :select => selections,
        :joins => 'LEFT JOIN users ON employee_locations.user_id=users.id LEFT JOIN location_states ON employee_locations.status_id=location_states.id',
        :conditions => conditions,
        :order => 'users.displayname ASC'
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, for now, I've decided to just perform a `caches_action` on the action which ultimately calls this method.  Seems to work fine for now, but I'm still interested in learning what someone else might have to say about the exception I experienced.

Comment: I just ran into this again, only this time with `Rails.cache.write()` and `.read()`: "`TypeError (<ModelName> can't be referred to)`"

Comment: Sounds like you need to force the Emlo class to be loaded or else rails doesn't know how to deserialize what's in memcache.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This problem arises in development mode when `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` AND `config.cache_classes = false` -- it seems ActiveRecord objects cannot be stored with `Rails.cache`.

But if you need to enable `config.action_controller.perform_caching` in development mode for testing caching, then you must also enable `config.cache_classes`.  This would be temporary, though, because then you'd have to restart the development server after changing classes or files in the asset pipeline.

With caching disabled, I would use `Rails.cache.write(some_name, some_value) if Rails.env.production?` to prevent caching from blowing up in development.  `Rails.cache.read()` doesn't seem to be affected.

Comment: LOL 10 years later this still hasn't been fixed!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered something similar storing an array of instances of a class via `Rails.cache.fetch(...) do` - it'd work fine until I changed any code (causing the app to be reloaded), then throw "...can't be referred to".

As @Matthew Clark mentions above it seems to be to do with the class being auto-reloaded because `config.cache_classes` is false in dev mode - this causes the objects stored with `Rails.cache.fetch` to be stale since they're effectively of a different class to the newly reloaded one.

In my case the class was a trivial one so I was able to move it to the `lib` directory so it's not auto-reloaded and `require` it in my code.  If this wasn't feasible, perhaps you could do something like `Rails.cache.fetch(... force: !Rails.configuration.cache_classes)` if you didn't mind the extra overhead in dev mode.

Answer (score 1):

Today, you can write a wrokarround following the idea of rails guides:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html#before-remove-const

Add into a `initializer` file the following code:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  unless Rails.application.config.cache_classes
    Rails.autoloaders.main.on_unload do |klass, _abspath|
      Rails.cache.clear
    end
  end
end
```

When some class must be reloaded then you clear the cache, and it will not fails, the only side effect will be a milliseconds more each time you change your code, and with every change, cache must be reloaded too.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the structure of your application, you might get an error in development like this:
TypeError (User can't be referred)
This error is caused by some caching-reloading madness: The middleware implanted by some gem is cached. But in development, your classes usually aren't. Thus some classes may not be available under certain circumstances, e.g. if you are using before filters for user authentication provided by some engine. You should be able to get rid of the error above by turning on class caching. Try it (and restart the server afterwards):

## development.rb

config.cache_classes = true

If the error is gone, you're lucky. But since it is not feasible to cache classes in development, turn off class caching again and explicitly require the class that couldn't be referred. I.E.:

## top of development.rb

require 'app/models/user'